# JAVA Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public LinkedList<MazeCoord> getPath() {

        return  getPath(); 
    }

public class MazeCoord {
   final private int row; // final (non-static) means it can't be updated once         
   final private int col; //      it's initialized

   // create a MazeCoord with the given row and column
   public MazeCoord(int row, int col) {
      this.row = row;
      this.col = col;
   }

   // get the row of this MazeCoord
   public int getRow() { return row; }

   // get the col of this MazeCoord;
   public int getCol() { return col; }

}
```

Why when I try to run this in my Eclipse, the console prompts me stack over flow?

Can any one tell me the reason?

Comment: This site has a search function. Use it before posting a new question.

Answer (score 6):

`getPath()` is calling itself, which causes an infinite chain of calls, that ends when the stack overflows. A correct recursive method must have a stopping condition.

Comment: Thanks,but how can I reuse the linkedlist if it can't return itself.
i.e. if I want to use getPath().add(...), how can I get the whole linked list?